# OpenGL scene coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: opengl, coordinates, glkit

I'm having trouble converting my OpenGL scene coordiates to my screen coordinates.

I thought I needed to multiply my coordinates with the modelview matrix then with the projection matrix to get the ndc. But i'm getting weird coordinates.

Here is my piece of code

```
GLKVector3 coor = GLKVector3Make(point.x, point.y, 0);
GLKMatrix4 modelview = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(glProjectionMatrix);
GLKMatrix4 projetion = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(modelViewMatrix.data);

GLKVector3 eyeCoor = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(modelview, coor);
GLKVector3 ndcCoor = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(projetion,eyeCoor);

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(ndcCoor.x, ndcCoor.y);
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code *seems* perfectly valid, but you should use 4D vectors for these homogeneous transforms.

So,

```
GLKVector4 coor = GLKVector4Make(point.x, point.y, 0, 1);

/// I hope those matrices are fine
GLKMatrix4 modelview = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(glProjectionMatrix);
GLKMatrix4 projetion = GLKMatrix4MakeWithArray(modelViewMatrix.data);

GLKVector4 eyeCoor = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(modelview, coor);
GLKVector4 ndcCoor = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector4(projetion,eyeCoor);

float XScr = ndcCoor.x / ndcCoor.w;
float YScr = ndcCoor.y / ndcCoor.w;

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(XScr, YScr);
```

If you want XScr and YScr to be in [0..1] range, then add

```
XScr = (XScr + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
YScr = (YScr + 1.0f) * 0.5f;
```

conversion.

Comment: With that i'm getting -inf,inf for x,y

Comment: Then remove the division by ndcCoor.w which is zero in this case (the point on the Unit Cube's boundary goes to infinity, thus w=0)

Comment: After, your solution was exact. The matrix I used were not the right ones !

Answer (score 1):

Even easier: use the GLKit Math function GLKMathProject.

```
GLKVector3 GLKMathProject (
   GLKVector3 object,
   GLKMatrix4 model,
   GLKMatrix4 projection,
   int *viewport
);
```

So, in your case, e.g.

```
int viewport[] = {0, 0, 320, 480};
GLKVector3 windowVector = GLKMathProject(coor, modelview, projetion, viewport);
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(windowVector.x, windowVector.y);
```

Note that the origin is at lower left, so if you're using UIKit coordinates where the origin is at the upper left, then switch the y coordinate, e.g.

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(windowVector.x, window.bounds.size.height - windowVector.y);
```