# OpenGL Scene to Screen Transformation

Tags: opengl, transformation

I want to use >OpenGL3 to render a **regular** 2D Hexagon to my Screen, but its much wider then it should be.

Here is my Hexagon Array (local coordinates):

```
float a[6][4] = {{ -1.0,0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { -sin30, cos30, 0.0f, 1.0f }, {-sin30, -cos30, 0.0f, 1.0f }, {sin30, cos30, 0.0f, 1.0f },{sin30, -cos30, 0.0f, 1.0f },{1.0, 0.0, 0.0f, 1.0f }};
```

Now i transform my Hexagon to World coordinates:

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        a[i][0] = a[i][0]*600+(float)width/2.0;
        a[i][1] = a[i][1]*600+(float)height/2.0;
        a[i][2] = a[i][2]*600;
        //a[i][3] = a[i][3]*600;
    }
```

My Vertex-Shader should now convert this to my screen:

```
float arr[4][4] = { {2.0/(float)width, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0},
                        {0.0, 2.0/(float)height, 0.0, -1.0},
                        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
                        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}};

char* code2 =
    {
        "#version 120\n"\
        "\n"\
        "layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
        "layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
        "out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
        "uniform mat4 Transform;\n"\
        "\n"\
        "void main(void)\n"\
        "{\n"\
        "   gl_Position = Transform*in_Position;\n"\
        "   ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
        "}\n"
    };
```

I work on a Windows PC and call glViewport(0,0,width,height); before and i draw only 2D Objects.
My shader get the correct Matrix (ColoumnMajor).
Some ideas to correct the deformation?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796059/opengl-scene-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates)

Comment: I dont think its duplicate: In your linked thread they call some functions and the rest is magic

Comment: Are `in`/`out` and `layout` actually working for you with `#version 120`?

Comment: It works correct: Different Matrix -> different picture on my screen. Normal i use `#version 400` with my nVidia PC. But my AMD Notebook have some problems, so i changed it to 120.

Comment: Recommend glm for a cleaner 3dmath code: http://glm.g-truc.net/